# Grep string in between two values Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a json data as below. Need to grep the value and export it into a new file.

```
{
"Data":
[
"User": [
      {"Name": "Solomon", "Age":20}, 
      {"Name": "Absolom", "Age":30}, 
   ] 
"Country": [
       {"Name" : "US", "Resident" : "Permanent"},
       {"Name" : "UK", "Resident" : "Temporary"}
]]}
```

Expected result,

Need to grep the value of "User" and export it to a new file User.json

User.json

```
"User": [
        {"Name": "Solomon", "Age":20}, 
        {"Name": "Absolom", "Age":30}, 
   ]
```

And again need to grep "Country" and export to Country.json

Country.json

```
"Country": [
       {"Name" : "US", "Resident" : "Permanent"},
       {"Name" : "UK", "Resident" : "Temporary"}
]
```

Was trying with `sed`, but am getting incorrect results

```
sed -e 's/.*"User"\(.*\)].*/\1/' Data.json > Users.json
```

Since there are many special characters `]/[/{/}` , not sure how to properly grep a value and export it to a new file.

Any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: Use json aware tool to extract json data. Use `jq`. No, you can't write json parser with sed.

Comment: No, don't want to part any data. I just need to grep and export it to a new file. Also i don't want to use `jq` as my linux distribution does not have `jq`

Comment: Again, that is not a valid JSON value. An array can not have an element in `"key": "value"` form.

Comment: Yes its not a valid JOSN, that the reason, i wanted to grep only required records and export into a new file

Comment: Okay, but the question body says it's a *json*, and that is wrong and might be misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enough luck you can use GNU sed with `-z` option and filter the content up until a closing `]` assuming there will be no `]` in the strings:

```
sed -z 's/.*\("User":[^]]*]\).*/\1\n/'
sed -z 's/.*\("Country":[^]]*]\).*/\1\n/'
```

Comment: `sed -z` is not working, am getting error as `sed -z illegal option`

Comment: Sure, install `GNU sed`. You can replace all newline in input to something and then use `sed` and then replace those characters back to newline. And still, if you are using BSD or OSX, it would be nice to specify your environment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a valid JSON, however, for parsing JSON you could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), for example, modifying your input a little bit, give a try to this:

```
 $ echo  '{
   "Data":[
      {
         "User":[
            {
               "Name":"Solomon",
               "Age":20
            },
            {
               "Name":"Absolom",
               "Age":30
            }
         ],
         "Country":[
            {
               "Name":"US",
               "Resident":"Permanent"
            },
            {
               "Name":"UK",
               "Resident":"Temporary"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}'| jq  -cr .'Data[] | with_entries(select(.key == "User"))';
```

It will output (for user):

```
{"User":[{"Name":"Solomon","Age":20},{"Name":"Absolom","Age":30}]}
```

And if you use `| jq  -cr .'Data[] | with_entries(select(.key == "Country"))';` (for country)

```
{"Country":[{"Name":"US","Resident":"Permanent"},{"Name":"UK","Resident":"Temporary"}]}
```

This is only one way of many possible, but I hope it can give you an idea.